# How to remove duplicate values from list using scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have following list

```
List(List
(43673,38448,512,36398,1500,**BpEwv+EcDv3z**,58f39535-03b7-4e05-a2d8-3f5b424c8938),
List(302750,759,512,759,3796,**BpEwv+EcDv3v**,069865df-30c3-48c3-bf02-79f2fcff7213),
List(616278,1600,512,107418,15255,**BpEwv+EcDv3v**,b373b731-6f38-4559-808e-1c05fc06af00),
List(0,0,512,0,0,**BpEwv+EcDv3z**,24894b9f-9e30-4073-a538-186a312c670e)
)
```

I want to remove duplicate values marked in bold (6th index of list for all elements) from this list. The sequence of elements is fixed.

Expected output:

```
List(
List(43673,38448,512,36398,1500,BpEwv+EcDv3z,58f39535-03b7-4e05-a2d8-3f5b424c8938),
List(302750,759,512,759,3796,BpEwv+EcDv3v,069865df-30c3-48c3-bf02-79f2fcff7213))
```

How do I remove duplicate values from list using scala??

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135627/in-scala-how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list).

Comment: I want it to work slighlty different. Here I want to remove duplicates only on fields marked as ** and in blue color and also its a list of list

Comment: You want to remove duplicates or you want to remove all occurrences of a specific value?

Comment: Can you see my edit please??? I have list of list and want list by remove whole inner list if any specific value gets duplicated..

Comment: Which is input data structure, `List[List[Any]]`, `List[List[String]]`?

Comment: @Sergey List[List[Any]]

Comment: Still unclear. Please provide your desired result, do you want to always remove 6th element? Do you want to remove based on value, etc.?

Comment: In my input, there are list of list i.e. list contains 4 lists. I want to make a single list from these 4 list my removing lists based on 6th element. It means I want to remove lists with duplicate (6th element)

Comment: Could you show expected output? Still unclear.

Comment: let me edit question

Comment: Just a suggestion, it will be useful to give values like A, B instead of BpEwv+EcDv3z and BpEwv+EcDv3v which is different by only one character. It took quite a long time to understand what you want even after the expected solution that you posted.

Comment: So why your expected output is just like your input?! I don't see anything removed from the first two `List`s! Please use simpler examples and exactly what you want to get as output. In the meantime please refer to the documentation of `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, and `distinct` methods on `List`. By doing that, most probably you will find the answer there or you can make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove all occurrences of a specific value in all `List`s you can use the following code:

```
val lss = List(List(1,2,2), List(1,2,3,4,2))

lss map (_.filter(_ != 2))           //  List(List(1), List(1, 3, 4))
```

which removes all occurrences of `2` in all `List`s.

If you want to get a single `List` in return you can use `flatMap`:

```
lss flatMap (_.filter(_ != 2))        // List(1, 1, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output, you can do something like

```
scala> val a = List(List
 | (43673,38448,512,36398,1500,"BpEwv+EcDv3z","58f39535-03b7-4e05-a2d8-3f5b424c8938"),
 | List(302750,759,512,759,3796,"BpEwv+EcDv3v","069865df-30c3-48c3-bf02-79f2fcff7213"),
 | List(616278,1600,512,107418,15255,"BpEwv+EcDv3v","b373b731-6f38-4559-808e-1c05fc06af00"),
 | List(0,0,512,0,0,"BpEwv+EcDv3z","24894b9f-9e30-4073-a538-186a312c670e")
 | )
a: List[List[Any]] = List(List(43673, 38448, 512, 36398, 1500, BpEwv+EcDv3z, 58f39535-03b7-4e05-a2d8-3f5b424c8938), List(302750, 759, 512, 759, 3796, BpEwv+EcDv3v, 069865df-30c3-48c3-bf02-79f2fcff7213), List(616278, 1600, 512, 107418, 15255, BpEwv+EcDv3v, b373b731-6f38-4559-808e-1c05fc06af00), List(0, 0, 512, 0, 0, BpEwv+EcDv3z, 24894b9f-9e30-4073-a538-186a312c670e))

scala> a.groupBy(_(5)).mapValues(_(0)).map(_._2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[Any]] = List(List(302750, 759, 51
2, 759, 3796, BpEwv+EcDv3v, 069865df-30c3-48c3-bf02-79f2fcff7213), List(43673, 3
8448, 512, 36398, 1500, BpEwv+EcDv3z, 58f39535-03b7-4e05-a2d8-3f5b424c8938))
```

You can also do which reads a little better

```
scala> a.groupBy(_(5)).mapValues(_(0)).values.toList
res6: List[List[Any]] = List(List(302750, 759, 512, 759, 3796, BpEwv+EcDv3v, 069865df-30c3-48c3-bf02-79f2fcff7213), List(43673, 38448, 512, 36398, 1500, BpEwv+EcDv3z, 58f39535-03b7-4e05-a2d83f5b424c8938))
```