# How to eliminate words that appear twice in an array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an `array` in **Scala**

```
val arr = Array("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d")
```

is there a way I can make it return only **"c"**, **"d"**

Comment: Did you try distinct?

Comment: refer this http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-find-unique-items-elements-list-sequence

Comment: @Pavel using distinct gives me the output "a", "b", "c", "d" but not "c", "d". I want to eliminate a and b because they repeat.

Comment: Agree, distinct not a good idea, what is the size of array by the way? any restrictions on data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, but I don't know if it is the best answer.

```
arr.groupBy(identity).filter(_._2.length == 1).map(_._1).toArray
```

This will return Array("c", "d")

Comment: @Thilo distinct will still return "a" and "b" in the result. OP wants to filter those out.

Comment: great works for me and solves my problem thanks for your solution @Sheunis

Answer (score 5):

```
arr.groupBy(identity).collect {
  case (str, instances) if instances.length == 1 => str
}
```

You can call `.toArray` at the end or whatever you want...

Comment: great @insan-e This works perfectly thanks for the answer

Comment: @udaykiran accept this answer, if it helped you, please

Comment: Similar alternative: `arr.groupBy(identity).collect { case (key, Array(single)) => key }`

Answer (score 1):

Try [Array#distinct](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#distinct:Repr)

```
scala> val arr = Array("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d")
arr: Array[String] = Array(a, a, b, b, c, d)

scala> arr.distinct
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)
```

By the way duplicate of [In Scala how do I remove duplicates from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135647/432903)

If you want non-duplicates values only, store by key and number of occurrence, then filter by occurrences.

```
  it("returns distincts only"){

    val array = Array("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d")

    val x = array.groupBy(identity)
      .filter(_._2.length == 1)
      .keys

    assert(x == Set("c", "d"))
  }
```

Comment: But it should return `Array(c, d)`

Comment: using distinct gives me the output "a", "b", "c", "d" but not "c", "d". I want to eliminate a and b because they repeat.

Answer (score 1):

```
val arr = Array("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d")
arr.foldRight(List[String]()){
  case (i,ar )=>
    if (arr.count(_==i)==1)
      i::ar
    else ar
}
```

Comment: It is a O(n^2) solution.

Comment: what's the size of the array?!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively but basically same approach

```
arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).filter(x => x._2 == 1).keys.toArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.groupBy(x=>x).filterNot(_._2.size==2).keys.toArray
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what do you want to optimize.

Lets say that you don't mind traversing multiple times. then something like,

```
val answer = array
  .groupBy(identity)
  .filter(_._2.length == 1)
  .map(_._1)
  .toArray
```

Or,

```
val answer = array
  .map(s => (s,1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .filter({ case (key, count) => count == 1 })
  .map({ case (key, count) => key })
  .toArray
```

But lets say you want to do it in a single traversal and don't mind using extra space, then you can do the following,

One thing to note it that we are going to need a "store" of already seen `Strings` and for each string in our array we have to check whether we have seen it or not.

So... the whole point here is to make the most appropriate choice for this store. And the most important requirement for this store here is that,

"It should provide an efficient (preferably constant time) `contains` or `exists` functionality".

And hence, `Set` is valid choice for our store.

Now,

```
val (_, answer) = array
  .foldLeft((Set.empty[String], Set.empty[String]))({
    case ((seen, collected), s) => seen.contains(s) match {
      case true => (seen, collected - s)
      case false => (seen + s, collected)
    }
  })
```